# What is the sql query to display the data types of each column in an oracle database table?

Tags: sql, oracle

What is the sql query to display the data types of each column in an oracle database table?

For example lets say I have a table called workflow_status with the following columns.

WORKFLOW_STATUS_ID, STATUS_NAME, LABEL, CREATED_DATE, UPDATED_DATE

What is the SQL query that will display the datatype of WORKFLOW_STATUS_ID, STATUS_NAME, LABEL, CREATED_DATE and UPDATED_DATE?

Comment: Did you even try to google it?

Comment: you need to query the db metadata for that info. Wikipedia has a pretty good rundown:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_metadata

Comment: check USER_TAB_COLUMNS for Oracle

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448860/how-to-view-all-the-metadata-of-columns-of-a-table-in-oracle-database

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, the `DESC` command is used to describe a table.

```
DESC workflow_status;
```