# How do I get all the column data in a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get all the column data in a table. For example I have a table called User and it has 2 columns name, hobby.

By running an sql query I want the following info.

```
name type=varchar2 length=50
hobby type=varchar2 length=100
```

Is there an SQL query that can be run to obtain this information? I am only able to find queries which tries to fetch the length of largest data in the column. But I want to get the actual length the column has been setup.

Using Datagrip but due to my read only access in production environment, I am not able to see the values in tree view. Please assist. Thanks.

Comment: I am assuming you are using Oracle database. Check the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448860/how-to-view-all-the-metadata-of-columns-of-a-table-in-oracle-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle you'd query the system views `user_tab_cols`, `all_tab_cols` or `dba_tab_cols`:

```
select * from user_tab_cols where table_name = :table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running in ORACLE prompt you can disperse the following command

```
DESC TABLE_NAME;
```

you will get query information

Answer (score -1):

If you are running in mysql prompt you can disperse the following command

describe tablename

For your example

mysql>describe User or desc User

You will be getting the required information

Comment: This is not mysql, this is oracle.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448860/how-to-view-all-the-metadata-of-columns-of-a-table-in-oracle-database

Comment: you may need to specify the meta data properties in a query and execute it